problem to my pointwise glyph code : pw::surface error
I'm working with pointwise glyph code. But there needs to be more code information on the internet. I'm writing code to make the nozzle and CFD domains using glyph. In my code, there is an inlet diameter of the nozzle. It works when the inlet diameter is 300.0 mm, but the error is printed out when it changes to 250.0 mm. Can you check my code to see what the problem is?
This code is related to the part where the error occurred :
proc making_surface { {surface_name "Hello world"} {component_a 0} {component_b 0} {component_c 0} {component_d 0} {component_e 0} {component_f 0}} {
    
    puts "Surface Name : \[$surface_name\]"
    
    global _Nozzle_Database
    global _Nozzle_surface
    set _Nozzle_surface(mode_21) [pw::Application begin Create]
    set _Nozzle_surface($surface_name) [pw::Surface createFromCurves -tolerance 0.001 [list $_Nozzle_Database($component_a) $_Nozzle_Database($component_b) $_Nozzle_Database($component_c) $_Nozzle_Database($component_d)]]
    
    $_Nozzle_surface(mode_21) end
    $_Nozzle_surface($surface_name) setName $surface_name
    return 21
}

set nozzle_curved_DB_name_list [list nozzle_curved_DB_center nozzle_curved_DB_py nozzle_curved_DB_pz nozzle_curved_DB_ny nozzle_curved_DB_nz] ; # 5
set core_nozzle_curved_DB_name_list [list core_nozzle_curve_DB_center core_nozzle_curve_DB_py core_nozzle_curve_DB_pz core_nozzle_curve_DB_ny core_nozzle_curve_DB_nz] ; # 5

set p1 [pwu::Vector3 set $front_straight $major_radius($i) 0.0] ; # py
puts [making_database 1 [lindex $nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 1] 0.0 $p1 $p1 [array get center_curve] [array get center_curve] 1.0  [array get x_domain] [array get major_radius]] ; # py nozzle line database
set pp1 [pwu::Vector3 set $front_straight $core_major_radius($i) 0.0] ; # py
puts [making_database 1 [lindex $core_nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 1] 0.0 $pp1 $pp1 [array get center_curve] [array get center_curve] 1.0 [array get x_domain] [array get core_major_radius]] 

set p1 [pwu::Vector3 set $front_straight 0.0 $minor_radius($i)] ; # pz
puts [making_database 1 [lindex $nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 2] 0.0 $p1 $p1 [array get center_curve] [array get center_curve] 1.0 [array get upper_line_x_domain] 0.0 [array get _tmp]] ; # pz nozzle line database
set pp1 [pwu::Vector3 set $front_straight 0.0 $core_minor_radius($i)] ; # pz
puts [making_database 1 [lindex $core_nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 2] 0.0 $pp1 $pp1 [array get center_curve] [array get center_curve] 1.0 [array get core_upper_line_x_domain] 0.0 [array get _ttmp]]

set inlet_radius 250.0 ; # [mm]
set major_radius($i) $inlet_radius ; # as [mm]
set boundary_layer_ratio 0.05
set core_section_ratio [expr {1.0-$boundary_layer_ratio}]
set core_major_radius($i) [expr {$major_radius($i) * $core_section_ratio}]

set i 0
set j 0
while { TRUE } {
    set x_domain($i) [expr {$j*$nozzle_curved}] ; #x_domain unit is [mm] 0 ~ nozzle_curved
    set x_domain_dimensionless($i) $j
    set j [expr {($j+$dx)}]
    incr i
    if { $j > [expr {1.0+$dx}] } {
        break
    }
}
set domain_size $i
set last_domain [expr {$domain_size-1}]

set _tmp_coons_path_name($i) "Coon_surface_2nd-0"
puts [making_surface $_tmp_coons_path_name($i) "nozzle_curved_DB_pz" "section_elipse_DB_2nd" "nozzle_curved_DB_ny" "section_elipse_DB_2nd-1"]
set _join_target_2nd [list $_Nozzle_surface($_tmp_coons_path_name($i))]

set _tmp_core_coons_path_name($i) "Core_coon_surface_2nd-0"
puts [making_surface $_tmp_core_coons_path_name($i) "core_nozzle_curve_DB_pz" "core_section_elipse_DB_2nd" "core_nozzle_curve_DB_ny" "core_section_elipse_DB_2nd-1"]
set _join_core_target_2nd [list $_Nozzle_surface($_tmp_core_coons_path_name($i))]

for {set i 1 } { $i < [expr {$domain_size -1 }] } { incr i } {
    set _tmp_DB_name_a [lindex $section_elipse_DB_2nd_name_list 0]
    append _tmp_DB_name_a "-$i"
    set _tmp_DB_name_b [lindex $section_elipse_DB_2nd_name_list 0]
    append _tmp_DB_name_b "-"
    append _tmp_DB_name_b [expr {$i+1}]
    set _tmp_coons_path_name($i) "Coon_surface_2nd"
    append _tmp_coons_path_name($i) "-"
    append _tmp_coons_path_name($i) $i
    puts [making_surface $_tmp_coons_path_name($i) $_tmp_DB_name_a [lindex $nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 2] $_tmp_DB_name_b [lindex $nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 3]]
    lappend _join_target_2nd $_Nozzle_surface($_tmp_coons_path_name($i))

    set _tmp_DB_name_a [lindex $core_section_elipse_DB_2nd_name_list 0]
    append _tmp_DB_name_a "-$i"
    set _tmp_DB_name_b [lindex $core_section_elipse_DB_2nd_name_list 0]
    append _tmp_DB_name_b "-"
    append _tmp_DB_name_b [expr {$i+1}]
    set _tmp_core_coons_path_name($i) "Core_coon_surface_2nd"
    append _tmp_core_coons_path_name($i) "-$i"
    puts [making_surface $_tmp_core_coons_path_name($i) $_tmp_DB_name_a [lindex $core_nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 2] $_tmp_DB_name_b [lindex $core_nozzle_curved_DB_name_list 3]]
    lappend _join_core_target_2nd $_Nozzle_surface($_tmp_core_coons_path_name($i))
}   

incr i
set _Nozzle_surface([lindex $joined_nozzle_wall_surface_name_list $i]) [pw::Surface join -reject _Nozzle_surface(ignored) $_join_target_2nd] 
$_Nozzle_surface([lindex $joined_nozzle_wall_surface_name_list $i]) setName [lindex $joined_nozzle_wall_surface_name_list $i]
set _Nozzle_surface([lindex $joined_nozzle_core_wall_surface_name_list $i]) [pw::Surface join -reject _Nozzle_surface(ignored) $_join_core_target_2nd]
$_Nozzle_surface([lindex $joined_nozzle_core_wall_surface_name_list $i]) setName [lindex $joined_nozzle_core_wall_surface_name_list $i]


When executing the last line in Pointwise, the error
invalid command name "::pw::Surface_4 ::pw::Surface_244 ::pw::Surface_276" while executing "$_Nozzle_surface([lindex $joined_nozzle_core_wall_surface_name_list $i]) setName [lindex $joined_nozzle_core_wall_surface_name_list $i]"
occurred.
I tried the pw:surface script, but there is no difference between inlet diameter 300mm and 250mm
So, I don't know what's problem.
I want to know what's problem and be debugged.
